# Why are there large discrepancies between Wald and bootstrapped confidence intervals for parameters of a lmer model in R?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am dealing with a multilevel model with gaussian error distribution that has ~21,000 observations and 5000 clusters. The model is of the simple form:

```
lmer(y ~ a + b + a:b + (1|z), weights=b)
```

and has weights applied in proportion to the variable `b`.

The behavior I'm encountering occurs when calculating confidence intervals of the fixed effects parameters with the following:

```
confint(mod, method="Wald")
confint(mod, method="profile") 
confint(mod1, method="boot", nsim=1000, parm="beta_")
```

The results from bootstrapping give confidence intervals that are ~3 times wider than the Wald results. The profile results throw a number of warnings such as:

> 1: In profile.merMod(object, which = parm, signames = oldNames, ...) :
>     non-monotonic profile for (Intercept)
>
> 6: In confint.thpr(pp, level = level, zeta = zeta) :
>     bad spline fit for (Intercept): falling back to linear interpolation

I have searched through many old threads that compare these methods, and I do expect the results from these methods to be different. However previous posts (and my own experience) suggests that usually these methods produce results that are not quite so far apart. I am looking for some intuition as to why this might occur and whether I am right to think that the bootstrapped results are probably more realistic (I suppose this means I should be skeptical of the SEs reported in `summary()` as well?).

I apologize for not providing a reproducible example, as I am not able to share the original data and my attempts to simulate the same issue only lead to situations in which the Wald and bootstrapped CIs were similar.

EDIT: Plot of profile:

[image]

Edit #2:
In response to Ben Bolker's comment below, the following code (stolen from elsewhere on the internet) simulates data for a mixed model and demonstrates that confint(..., method="profile") fails when weights are included as well as some differences in CIs from the different methods.

```
library(mvtnorm)
set.seed(2345)

N <- 150
unit.df <- data.frame(unit = c(1:N), a = rnorm(N))
unit.df <-  within(unit.df, {
  E.alpha.given.a <-  1 - 0.15 * a
  E.beta.given.a <-  3 + 0.3 * a
})

q = 0.2
r = 0.9
s = 0.5
cov.matrix <- matrix(c(q^2, r * q * s, r * q * s, s^2), nrow = 2,
                     byrow = TRUE)
random.effects <- rmvnorm(N, mean = c(0, 0), sigma = cov.matrix)
unit.df$alpha <- unit.df$E.alpha.given.a + random.effects[, 1]
unit.df$beta <- unit.df$E.beta.given.a + random.effects[, 2]

J <- 300
M = J * N  #Total number of observations
x.grid = seq(-4, 4, by = 8/J)[0:30]
within.unit.df <-  data.frame(unit = sort(rep(c(1:N), J)), j = rep(c(1:J),N), x =rep(x.grid, N))
flat.df = merge(unit.df, within.unit.df)

flat.df <-  within(flat.df, y <-  alpha + x * beta + 0.75 * rnorm(n = M))
simple.df <-  flat.df[, c("unit", "a", "x", "y")]
simple.df$wht <- rpois(n = dim(simple.df)[1], lambda = 5)+1

my.lmer <-  lmer(y ~ x + a + x * a + wht + (1 | unit), data = simple.df, weights = wht)
summary(my.lmer)

confint(my.lmer, method="Wald")
confint(my.lmer, method="profile")
confint(my.lmer, method="boot", nsim=100)
```

Comment: Would it be appropriate to cross-post after already posting here? Plotting the profiles yields the following output:

Comment: OK, I should have been more clear about the plotting. `pp <- profile(mod); lattice::xyplot(pp)` (you'll want to save the profile object, as it's pretty slow to compute)

Comment: I actually tried that first using code from one of your posts, but got the following error: "Error in data.frame(y = r[[".zeta"]], x = r[[n]]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 49, 0 " -- the other plotting methods for class "thpr" objects also throw errors. Any advice?

Comment: Yes.  Follow this example: `library(lme4); fm1 <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject), sleepstudy); pp <- profile(fm1, signames=FALSE); library(ggplot2); ggplot(as.data.frame(pp),
       aes(.focal,.zeta)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~.par,scale="free_x")`

Comment: That worked. Does it seems like something is going wonky near the boundaries?

Comment: certainly wonky.  Maybe `scale="free"` (i.e., free in both x and y directions) would be slightly more useful?  Is there anything else funny about the data/fitting (e.g., any other warnings?)

Comment: Updated with scale="free". There really isn't anything else seemingly problematic with the data or fitting. No warnings, residual plot looks great, plotting predictions onto the raw data looks very reasonable. Variables are all on similar scales. That is why I was so surprised by the behavior of confint().

Comment: Just refit the model without weights and the profile plots now look normal (I think -- all showing linear increase from bottom left to upper right across range). Is it obvious why weights would be having this effect, or does that illuminate the original problem?

Comment: Not sure. It's conceivable that there's a bug somewhere that's triggered by weights + profile (weights have always been a little problematic/under-tested).  (1) Does simulated data with weights display similar problems? (2) Are the weights extreme or weird in any way?

Comment: The weights I'm using aren't exteme in any obvious way (poisson distribution, all greater than 2, not extremely long tailed). With simulated data, adding weights does in fact cause method="profile" in confint() to throw the same errors as I was getting in my data. It also skews differences between the bootstrapped values and Wald somewhat, but not at the level in my original data. Would it help if I shared this simulation code? How to best do so without clogging this thread?

Comment: As long as the simulation code is not horribly long, editing your question to include it would be great.  If it is super-long, maybe post it elsewhere (as a gist or something) and link to it ...

Comment: Nice to have reproducible code. FWIW, I've noticed that the warnings from the `profile` method appear even with the simplest weighted random effects model. Applied to `lmer(y ~ (1 | unit), data = simple.df, weights = wht)`, the profile method for `confint()` gives the noted warnings for `(Intercept)`.

Comment: @BenBolker in the interest of not letting this be forgotten, is there something that should be done to notify developers of this issue with weighted models? If there was a way to verify that the bootstrapped CIs are working for weighted models (I'm not sure how to do this) then another good option could maybe be to update your GLMM FAQ page to note that bootstrap and not profile methods should be used for such models.

Comment: "developers" is more or less me at this point :-(  I don't know whether I already posted this to the lme4 issues list on github, but that's definitely the right place for it to not be forgotten.

Comment: If I can ask, how do you interpret the plot that it is in the question, the one that is .focal and .zeta ? (profiles, pp plot)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the Wald statistic is not good and you shouldn't trust it for mixed models. It uses a much cruder approximation to the actual likelihood than you get with the `profile` and `boot.ci` methods. If R (and SAS and JMP and...) would have been written today, they would not have bothered implementing Wald stats. That's why the `summary.merMod` method *intentionally* omits $p$-values from the fixed effect coefficient output. The computational intensity of profile/bootstrap is at most on the scale of minutes by today's standards, but in the olden days, it would take weeks. So, the analyst was expected to do massive amounts of testing and variable transformation methods so that Wald stat might have good-ish properties.

**EDIT**: below is a snippet of a conversation between me, David Dahl, and Douglas Bates back in 2010 when I tried to suggest using the Wald $p$-values for `xtable`.

> > A user of your lme4 package would like to use xtable on mer objects
> >     from lme4.  That means defining a function "xtable.mer".  He suggests
> >     the implementation below.  I regrettably am not very familar with
> >     lme4.  Do you have any suggestions?
>
> I appreciate Adam's suggestion and his providing an implementation.
>   Regrettably, I think that the implementation would be controversial,
>   to say the least, and I would prefer not to be the recipient of the
>   fallout.  There is a long-standing issue with lme4 regarding p-values
>   on tests of the fixed-effects parameters.  For linear mixed models
>   there is a widespread belief that you can calculate a t-statistic
>   (what is labelled here as a "z value") and convert it to a p-value by
>   the simple expedient of determining an approximate number of degrees
>   of freedom.  In fact, SAS PROC MIXED offers several (6, I believe)
>   different, and incompatible, ways of determining such degrees of
>   freedom and the corresponding p-values.  The fact that these give
>   different answers doesn't deter people from regarding such
>   approximations as "absolute truth".
>
> In reality the distribution of such a statistic is not a Student's T.
>   It is much more complicated than that and I advocate other ways of
>   calculating confidence intervals or testing hypotheses.  In the case
>   of a generalized linear mixed model I do calculate a p-value from the
>   standard normal distribution, not because the approximation is better
>   for GLMMs than for LMMs but because it is worse.
>
> I am writing a book for Springer on lme4 (chapter drafts are available
>   at http://lme4.R-forge.R-project.org/book/) where I describe using
>   likelihood ratio tests for hypothesis tests and techniques based on
>   profiling the LRT statistic to produce confidence intervals on
>   parameters.  The examples in that book are based on the development
>   version of the package which uses a different representation of the
>   model.  The implementation is not complete, which is why I haven't
>   released it as lme4, but right now I need to concentrate on the
>   writing because the book is going to be used in a seminar which starts
>   next week.

Comment: I don't really agree with this.  It's true that Wald statistics are inferior to profile and parametric bootstrap statistics, but they're orders of magnitude faster, and in many cases they're good enough. (Typically better for fixed effects than for random-effects parameters [variances & covariances]; for REs they're better on log than on linear scales ... all other things being equal, they're better for larger data sets, which is exactly when you need speed) The trick is knowing when.

Comment: And ... summary.merMod omits p-values because denominator dfs are hard, not because Wald intervals are bad. The standard errors quoted in `summary` are *exactly* Wald-type estimates ...

Comment: In relation to this last comment: is there an obvious way to get bootstrapped or profile SEs rather than Wald SEs reported in summary? It's not exactly clear to me why Doug Bates did not want the Wald SEs omitted for the same reason as the p-values.

Comment: @BenBolker hmm, can you link a reference on denominator dfs? Curious to patch up any misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: @TKraft I think what you are looking for is the `confint.merMod()` function in the `lme4` package.

Comment: @AdamO various references are available, with alternative. [1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2533558?), [2](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610928808829672) and [3](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02288586) would probably be some often cited origins. The latter is only concerned with single parameter test, while the first two concerns multivariate test of fixed effects. These are implemented in the [lmerTest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmerTest/index.html) package. Also bootstrapping becomes overly slow if the number of observations becomes large.

Comment: Note that the above mentioned references are not really what i'd called simple material. I do however agree that one should be careful with the standard wald-test, as it may become very misleading indeed, even in situations where one would feel it shouldn't be. The approximations quoted might be good alternatives to bootstrapping.